# Inactivity limit VS Screen saver timeout GPO Policy

Tags: windows, security, active-directory, group-policy

We are trying to decided between, the **Computer** vs **User** GPO Policies to force the screen to lock for our user workstations. Both seem to have the same overall effect of evoking the screen saver, effectively locking the users session.

[image]

Are there any advantages or disadvantages to either of these methods?

**Interactive Logon: Machine inactivity limit Properties**

```
Computer configuration polices
└──Policies
   └──Windows Settings
      └──Security Settings
         └──Local Polices
            └──Security Options
               └──Interactive Logon: Machine inactivity limit Properties
```

VS

**Screen Saver Timeout**

```
User Configuration
└──Administrative Templates
   └──Control Panel
      └──Personalization.  
         └──Screen saver timeout
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't profess to be an expert on the subject but my summation of the two different settings is this:

**Inactivity timeout:** is a workstation security setting and will always require any user to authenticate after the set period of inactivity.

**Screen Saver:** is a user setting and users may have more aggressive timeouts based on their role/scope. Screen saver also does not force re-authentication unless the "Password protect the screen saver" is also enabled.